Cannot GET / выходит ошибка при загрузки страницы
учу сейчас node js и никак не могу понять в чем проблема,при запуски модуля webpack-dev-server по http://localhost:8080/ выходит ошибка Cannot GET /
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "watch": "webpack -- watch",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}



Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки и полную команду, которая приводит к этой ошибке. Дополнительно, можно скрин приложить
